# RAID controller question: NVDIMM or not?

Tags: raid, hardware-raid

I am in the market for a new RAID controller for a Dell server, and I have a choice between "PERC H700 512mb Cache" and "PERC H700 512mb NVDIMM Cache". There is a $200 difference between the 2 cards, can anyone recommend either one? Is the second option worth the extra $200?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NVDIMM is a new technology that avoids the need for a battery-backed cache by preserving the data in memory even in the event of power loss.  [This article](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/storage/non-volatile-dimms-immortal-dram/1055) seems like a reasonable primer to the technology.

As to whether it's worth it, I'm not sure.  I've never had a reliability problem with the BBU in a RAID controller, nor have I had a server down for long enough that the battery fully discharged, but if that was something that made you nervous, it might be worth the extra $200 for peace of mind.  I doubt the performance will be substantively different.